# jsPDF Autotable API?

Tags: javascript, jspdf-autotable

Just found the Autotable plugin for jsPDF and there seems to be a little bit of a learning curve for me as I try to use this.  I see the examples.js that comes with the file, but is there a full API somewhere where I can see all methods?

For example the didParseCell section there is this code:

```
  // Use for customizing texts or styles of specific cells after they have been formatted by this plugin.
// This hook is called just before the column width and other features are computed.
  didParseCell: function (data) {
  if (data.row.index === 5) {
    data.cell.styles.fillColor = [40, 170, 100]
  }

  if (
    (data.row.section === 'head' || data.row.section === 'foot') &&
    data.column.dataKey === 'expenses'
  ) {
    data.cell.text = '' // Use an icon in didDrawCell instead
  }

  if (data.column.dataKey === 'city') {
    data.cell.styles.font = 'mitubachi'
    if (data.row.section === 'head') {
      data.cell.text = 'シティ'
    }
    if (data.row.index === 0 && data.row.section === 'body') {
      data.cell.text = 'とうきょう'
    }
  }
},
```

I'd like to know what methods/properties I can access for "data".  Is there a full API that lists these somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [readme.md](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/README.md) available as documentation. For more details they are suggesting to read the class definitions for HookData, Table, Row, Cell etc. defined in [models.ts](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/463fbffb176203e43c381f3f67565153b742284f/src/models.ts#L160):

> To see what is included in the Table, Row, Column and Cell types, either log them to the console or take a look at src/models.ts

For ready reference here are the definitions:

```
class HookData {
  table: Table
  pageNumber: number
  pageCount: number // Deprecated, use pageNumber instead
  settings: Settings
  doc: jsPDFDocument
  cursor: Pos | null
}

class CellHookData extends HookData {
  cell: Cell
  row: Row
  column: Column
  section: 'head' | 'body' | 'foot'
}

class Table {
  id?: string | number
  settings: Settings
  styles: StylesProps
  hooks: HookProps
  columns: Column[]
  head: Row[]
  body: Row[]
  foot: Row[]
  pageNumber = 1
  finalY?: number
  startPageNumber?: number
}

class Row {
  readonly raw: HTMLTableRowElement | RowInput
  readonly element?: HTMLTableRowElement
  readonly index: number
  readonly section: Section
  readonly cells: { [key: string]: Cell }
  spansMultiplePages: boolean

  height = 0
}

class Cell {
  raw: HTMLTableCellElement | CellInput
  styles: Styles
  text: string[]
  section: Section
  colSpan: number
  rowSpan: number

  contentHeight = 0
  contentWidth = 0
  wrappedWidth = 0
  minReadableWidth = 0
  minWidth = 0

  width = 0
  height = 0
  x = 0
  y = 0
}

class Column {
  raw: ColumnInput | null
  dataKey: string | number
  index: number

  wrappedWidth = 0
  minReadableWidth = 0
  minWidth = 0
  width = 0
}
```